# Asp.Net Core 3.1 Seed data with conditionally

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I don't want to seed if the data exist in the `modelBuilder`.

Here is I tried and seeded again with different `role ids` so my user with the roles has gone.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
            new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() },
            new IdentityRole { Name = "PoUser", NormalizedName = "PoUser".ToUpper() },
            new IdentityRole { Name = "User", NormalizedName = "User".ToUpper() }
        );

    }
```

So how can I prevent data seeding with conditional rendering in Asp.Net Core 3.1 if data exist in the db ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you must add a primary key into the model.

```
builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
        new IdentityRole { Id = 1, Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() },
        new IdentityRole { Id = 2, Name = "PoUser", NormalizedName = "PoUser".ToUpper() },
        new IdentityRole { Id = 3, Name = "User", NormalizedName = "User".ToUpper() }
    );
```

Because it will be used to detect data changes between migrations.

About [Data Seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding).

Hope this could helps.

Comment: Bu ids are guid string. it is not int.Then can you show me pls for guid that should be same guid when app starts everytime?

Comment: You can start using int as key if you need to seed data with precise IDs every time. Start using IdentityRole<int> instead of Indentity Role will do the trick.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityrole-1?view=aspnetcore-1.1

Comment: I set the string default value.

Comment: Use code like this: Guid("F9168C5E-CEB2-4faa-B6BF-329BF39FA1E4"). Instead of "F9168C5E-CEB2-4faa-B6BF-329BF39FA1E4" you can set your string value.

Answer (score 0):

`Entity framework` uses a `primary key` for preventing data duplication. Always define the primary key if you don't want the data to be deleted and recreated in `seed` method.

As you are using `Microsoft Identity` so Primary Key of `IdentityRole` class is a string. Your code should be like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
        new IdentityRole { Id = "9919cdf5-d72d-4cb2-83dc-34017017eed7", Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() },
        new IdentityRole { Id = "5f6ee6bc-49ef-49ba-a7a2-271a1f2c9ce1", Name = "PoUser", NormalizedName = "PoUser".ToUpper() },
        new IdentityRole { Id = "297da0fc-170f-4ead-b04e-ee431efcbd63", Name = "User", NormalizedName = "User".ToUpper() }
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
        new IdentityRole { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() },
        new IdentityRole { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "PoUser", NormalizedName = "PoUser".ToUpper() },
        new IdentityRole { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "User", NormalizedName = "User".ToUpper() }
    );

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).